# Killing Apache spark job from web UI is not killing its python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, subprocess

pyspark code written to call another python job using subprocess.Popen(command)

Tried to kill Sparkcontext manually from spark master web UI http://localhost:8080 and it killed successfully

by the time python subprocess triggered and running in worker node as a python process.

Using Redhatlinux

How to kill python subprocess if I kill pyspark sparkcontext?

Comment: Is you question about how to kill the stale processes after the fact, or how to write your app so it cleans up after itself?

Comment: I wrote code to clean up part if the job gets success or fails.Looking for solutions which deals between sparkcontext session and python session.More info current running spark job triggered from spark API,driver and the application shows in spark master web UI.If I kill driver it auto kills the application on workers as well from UI.But,My python subprocess triggered from spark JOB runs background,I can see the process in a worker node through shell command and It won't show in slave UI http://loclhost:8081.I need if I kill spark app driver all sub process triggers by spark job should kill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
import sys, os, subprocess, signal, time

@contextmanager
def spark_manager():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("TEST-SPARK")
    conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    try:
        yield sc
    finally:
        sc.stop()

with spark_manager() as context:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'test.py'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    # Poll process for new output until finished
    while True:
        if context._jsc.sc().isStopped():
            print(process.pid)
            time.sleep(1.0)
            os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
            break
        nextline = process.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(nextline)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    output = process.communicate()[0]
    exitCode = process.returncode

    if (exitCode == 0):
        print(output)
    else:
        raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it's quite hard to kill a subprocess reliably because the subprocess can be executing uninterruptible code when you want to kill it. That being said, it sounds like a "best effort" approach might be appropriate for your case. You'll want to create and wait on your subprocess in a way allows you to clean up if the process is interrupted. The easiest way to do this is to put your subprocess in a try/finally block.

```
try:
    print("starting subprocess")
    x = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "100000"])
    x.wait()
finally:
    print("stopping subprocess")
    x.terminate()
```

I believe spark sends an interrupt signal

Comment: Hi Rico, Thanks for comment! I tried but didn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? the finally block wasn't reached? terminate was called but the process didn't quit ... did you get some kind of error message.

Comment: finally block wan't reached when I killed job from UI and no error message was shown. sub process was running in worker machine still. stopping subprocess message shown after process completion